# Dynamodb UpdateExpression: "REMOVE #items[0]" appends new list element?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a Dynamodb table containing a List `items`. I'm looking to remove an element from this list, given a specified `index` (using index 0 to test):

```
docClient.update({
    TableName: 'cart',
    Key: { 'id': id },
    ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW',
    UpdateExpression: "REMOVE #items[0]",
    ExpressionAttributeNames : {
        "#items": "items"
    }
},  function(err, data) {   
    })
```

Instead of removing element `0` from the items list, it appends a new element (map) (please see attached pic of the last appended element)

...what am I doing wrong? Also, how should I be substituting a variable in place of 0, above? I tried:

```
...
UpdateExpression: "REMOVE #items[:index]",
ExpressionAttributeValues :
":index": index
},
...
```

...which results in error: `Invalid UpdateExpression: Syntax error; token: \":index\", near: \"[:index]`

Thank you so much!

[image: dynamodb table]

AWS-SDK: ^2.500.0

node: v10.16.0

--
EDIT: 
1) AWS SDK doesn't support `ExpressionAttributeValues` with REMOVE, so I have to `"REMOVE List[" + listNumber + "]"`, instead.
2) Changing  `UpdateExpression: "REMOVE #items[0]"` to `UpdateExpression: "REMOVE #i[0]"` for 
`ExpressionAttributeValues : { ":i": items }` removed element 0 properly; however, DynamoDB is still appending a new list element `Index : i` where i was the index that I was removing.

Is this a bug?

[image: dynamodb appending items]

Comment: can you share the screenshot of the Item in text format from the console? also, can you rename items to something else, I'm not sure if it's clashing with the reserved keywords

Comment: @AniruddhaRaje image added. Here you can see a bunch of new elements of type map that were appended. If I were to call "REMOVE #i[0]" it would append element "M" : {"index" : {"N" : "0" } }  after element 0 was removed. Strange.

Comment: is the items field a sort key or just normal field ?

Comment: @AniruddhaRaje just a normal field. I just changed 'items' to 'cartitems' and the behavior didn't change.

Comment: I'm able to remove via the CLI command, maybe you can try the same using SDK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to remove an element from the `cart_items` field as below -

**table name -** `cart`

**here is my data -**

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "cart_items": [
    "1", "2"
  ]
}
```

**AWS CLI query to remove 1st element from the cart_items array -**

```
aws dynamodb update-item \
    --table-name cart \
    --key '{"id":{"S":"1"}}' \
    --update-expression "REMOVE cart_items[0]" \
    --return-values ALL_NEW
```

Comment: That worked for me successfully, without having an additional item appended. I think I've run into a bug with the nodejs aws-sdk

Comment: Thanks for your time my friend.

Comment: happy to help :)